# Query for an empty time range in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently discovered that a time range can be `empty` which appears to be different vs a `null` field.

```
db=# select tstzrange(now(), now());
 tstzrange
-----------
 empty
(1 row)

db=# select tstzrange(now(), now()) is null;
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

How can I match an `empty` field for a query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compare it with a string `'empty'`

```
select tstzrange(now(), now()) = 'empty' as out
```

which produces:

```
 out
-----
 t
```

While for a non-empty result with query like:

```
select tstzrange(now(), now() + interval '1d') = 'empty' as out
```

it consistently produces:

```
 out
-----
 f
```

In fact implicit conversion of `'empty'::tstzrange` takes place.

Read more on the matter in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-IO)

Comment: Great! Thank you!
I'm curious why it works this way, how can a `tstzrange` type eval against a string `'empty'`?

Comment: See how it's implemented: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-IO
There is an implicit conversion of `'empty'` to `tstzrange` type.

Answer (score 3):

use [isempty()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)

```sql
select isempty(tstzrange(now(), now())); -- true
select isempty(tstzrange(now(), now() + interval '1d')); -- false
```

Comment: This also seems to work for multiranges (at least in postgres 15), making it a more useful answer than relying on the implicit cast from string to range.